# mkvirtualenv is throwing an error during mkvirtualenv and workon

Tags: python, powershell, virtualenvwrapper

I am on Win7, installed python 2.7.7 x64, installed pip 1.5.6, installed virtualenv 1.11.6 and virtualenvwrapper 12.7.8. I installed pip/virtualenv/virtualenvwrapper using powershell prompt.  I created an env and get the below error.  I also get it when I do "workon test1" to change to the env.

```
    PS C:\Users\rowidema\Envs> mkvirtualenv test1
    New python executable in test1\Scripts\python.exe
    Installing setuptools, pip...done.
    The argument '~\Envs\VEW_PreMakeVirtualEnv.ps1' to the -File parameter does not exist. Provide the path to an existing '.ps1' file as an argument to the -File parameter.
    Added activation script por Powershell to ~/Envs/test1\Scripts.
    The argument '~\Envs\VEW_PreActivateVirtualEnv.ps1' to the -File parameter does not exist. Provide the path to an existing '.ps1' file as an argument to the -File parameter.
```

I cant find the script that is actually run to find out what -File is actually expecting.
Thanks
Robert

Comment: after rebooting today I get following:
        PS C:\Users\rowidema\Envs> workon
        WARNING: Can't find path 'C:\Users\rowidema/.virtualenvs' ($VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_HOOK_DIR). Defaulting to $env:WORKON_HOME. workon : The 'workon' command was found in the module 'VirtualEnvWrapper', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module VirtualEnvWrapper'.
        At line:1 char:1
        + workon
        + ~~~~~~
            + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (workon:String) [], CommandNotFoundException    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule